# How to use jukeboxAI error ERROR: Could not build wheels for numba, llvmlite, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, numba, openai-api, python-wheel

I'm trying to run this colab build by openAI: https://github.com/openai/jukebox

you can see the colab link on github : https://colab.research.google.com/github/openai/jukebox/blob/master/jukebox/Interacting_with_Jukebox.ipynb

But when i run : `!pip install git+https://github.com/openai/jukebox.git`

I have this error :

```
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
 Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... error
 ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
 Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Successfully built jukebox fire librosa mpi4py
Failed to build numba llvmlite
**ERROR: Could not build wheels for numba, llvmlite, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects**
```

Answer (score 0):

same issue here with solution :
https://github.com/openai/jukebox/issues/276

you must switch to another git source since google collab upgrade python and open AI project seems not compatible